# How to trigger mail notification in BigQuery when any data attributes value cross certain value?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How to trigger mail notification in BigQuery when any data attributes value cross certain value?
For ex-
If the threshold for Quantity of any product is set to 1000 and if that values exceeds 1000, then automatically it should trigger an email to the configured user.

Answer (score 0):

How real time do you want these notifications? If checks a few times a day are OK, a simple solution is to schedule a query in BigQuery that performs all these value checks, and fails if something is wrong using ERROR function. Configure the scheduled query to send email notifications if query fails, and that's all.

Your query will look like:

```
SELECT ERROR(CONCAT("Over threshold: ", CAST(quantity AS STRING)))
FROM `proj.dataset.table` 
WHERE quantity > 1000
```

Now create this query in UI, test it, then click Schedule this query, enter name and schedule, make sure Notification options > Send email notifications is checked, and that's all. If the threshold is exceeded when the query is run, you get notification.

Comment: Frequency can be hourly or once per day, I don't want to check errors. Just it will check based on frequency set whether threshold reached. If it reach threshold it should immediately trigger an email to the user. Could you please help in providing end to end solution to such scenario.?

Comment: I added some details that hopefully help you.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I may be silly for asking this question because I relatively new to google cloud/ Big Query. What if I want to trigger this mail notification to the group of users ?

Comment: What if I want to trigger this mail notification to the group of users ?